# I'm getting a Content Decoding Error when using the image manager for 2sxc module

Tags: 2sxc

Images in the image manager when editing an item are showing as broken images. It looks to be an issue with the ImageResizer on my install. If I remove the [w h mode="crop"], the image will display. If I look in the dev console when pulling up the image manager I get `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED`.

I upgraded to the latest version of 2sxc on client staging site and I am able to reproduce same issue.

Client is on an older version (07.04.02 (216)) of DNN. 
Is this possibly related to us needing to upgrade their dnn install?

Comment: I would look at the resulting stream - my guess is that the server is intercepting these through some other http-handler resulting in something very unexpected. So my guess is that the image handler isn't even involved.

Comment: Thank @iJungleBoy. I'm looking in my webconfig and I'm not seeing anything that's set to intercept image types. Some additional context, I did remove the `<add name="ImageResizingModule" type="ImageResizer.InterceptModule" />` from the `<modules>` node, cleared cache and the images are showing but now not being resized. Adding this back I am able to reproduce the issue. What else should I be looking for if something is intercepting images?

Comment: Thanks, your tests seems to ensure that it is caused by the resizer. From your video on the github issue I saw that some images showed up, others didn't. Could you call a resize url directly in your browser and see what is returned? do you get html (instead of an image), just some error text or what?

Comment: @iJungleBoy, correct. It's odd, some images do show but other are not. If I take an image path of one that is not showing and open that up in a new tab, I get: 
`The webpage at https://www.ascconline.org/Portals/0/01%20ASCC%206%20in%20CMYK.jpg?w=120&h=120&mode=crop might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED`

Open one in the new tab that you can see works fine. 

Could it be the way the client has named their images?

Comment: ok @iJungleBoy, even renaming some images to use hyphens "-" instead of spaces in image name, still produces same results.

Comment: I tried a few things but I don't have an answer. My guess is that it only fails on cmyk images (instead of RGB) - but that's just a big guess. And why that would be the case I wouldn't know either.
I suggest you try a few different images and check your event errors in the windows log. It may also be fixed by updating to a newer version of image-resizer, as the one we include is certainly 2 years old or so, but we've never had any issues so far.